# RegEx replace/remove all periods inside brackets

Tags: regex

I have MDX data formatted like this:

```
[Measures].[Gross Revenue(Exl. Post-Or Disc.)]
```

And my split logic to separate to group these (e.g. Arr('[Measures]', '[Gross Revenue(Exl. Post-Or Disc.)]') is currently getting hung on the abbreviated parts. Granted it's not perfect, but the easiest way to deal with this would be to remove all periods within the brackets.

My current RegEx:

```
RegExReplace('[Measures].[Gross Revenue(Exl. Post-Or Disc.)]', '\[(.*?)\]', '', 1)
```

Is currently giving me:

```
.
```

Ideally, this should look like:

```
[Measures].[Gross Revenue(Exl Post-Or Disc)]
```

I'm pretty horrible with RegEx and can't figure out how to escape this period for the life of me, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated- thanks!

Comment: Use `'\.(?=[^][]*])'`. Is it AHK?

Comment: Which language are you working with (for `RegExReplace`, ...)?

Comment: If it is AHK, then it is PCRE. And a fancy PCRE regex to make sure we do exclude matching `.`s inside `[...]`: [`(?:^[^[]*|][^[]*$|][^][]*\[)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.`](https://regex101.com/r/wL2eE1/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know enough about RegEx to know all the alternatives, but your first expression worked fantastically for me- thank you! I wish you submitted it as an answer!

Comment: @trincot I should've stated that upfront- I'm working with C#'s RegEx class.

Comment: In .NET, you may even use `(?<=\[[^][]*)\.(?=[^][]*])` to really match any dot *inside* a `[` and `]`. The accepted answer only matches dots that are not preceded with a `]` or not followed with `[`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The period `.` is actually a special character in regex and means "any character." To use a special character as a literal, you have to "escape" it. Usually the escape character is a backslash `\`.

Please let me know if this expression solves your problem:

```
(?<!\])\.(?!\[)
```

There are three parts to this expression:

1. `(?<!\])` ← Negative lookbehind meaning "not preceded by a close bracket"
2. `\.` ← Literal period
3. `(?!\[)` ← Negative lookahead meaning "not followed by an open bracket"

In ordinary language, it makes sense to read these in the order 2, 1, 3: a period not preceded by a close bracket nor followed by an open bracket.

For more information on regular expressions, please see regular-expressions.info, in particular this page on "lookaheads" and "lookbehinds": http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

If you'd like more practice, this site has a nice interface for testing and trying regular expressions: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This worked beautifully for me! 

Thanks for breaking down each section and for providing those helpful resources. I've idiotically been trying to learn via [https://regexcrossword.com/](https://regexcrossword.com/). Definitely better for brushing up with than to use as a learning resource.

Comment: I'm so glad! I am a relatively new contributor here. For me this is a fun and productive way to connect with people on the internet. Have a great day!

Comment: Do not rely on regex101 when testing .NET regex , the site does not support .NET regex syntax. Use Ultrapico Expresso tool. Also, there is no point escaping `]` outside of a character class.